# Query to Return Count of SKU's purchased by Customer

Tags: sql, firebird, razorsql

I know this is elementary to most of you, I don't use SQL that much.  I am trying to return a dataset that shows the following:

```
CustomerID     #DistinctSKUsPurchased
```

Here is the query I am using, joining the SalesOrder (SO) table with SalesOrderItem (SOITEM) table:

```
SELECT SO.ID, SOITEM.SOID, SO.CustomerID, COUNT(DISTINCT SOITEM.ProductID)  
FROM SOITEM
INNER JOIN SO
ON SO.ID=SOITEM.SOID
ORDER BY SO.ID;
```

I am getting a syntax error which says:

```
ERROR: GDS Exception. 335544569. Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error
code = -104
Invalid expression in the select list (not contained
in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause)
Error
Code: 335544569

Query = SELECT SO.ID, SOITEM.SOID, SO.CustomerID,
COUNT(DISTINCT SOITEM.ProductID)  
FROM SOITEM
INNER
JOIN SO
ON SO.ID=SOITEM.SOID
ORDER BY SO.ID;
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `Group by` clause.  Which SQL is this?  MySql? Oracle? SQL Server?

Comment: I am connecting to a Firebird database using RazorSQL

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `GROUP BY` clause which includes all columns of the select list not used in an aggregate function.

```
SELECT SO.ID, SOITEM.SOID, SO.CustomerID, COUNT(DISTINCT SOITEM.ProductID)
FROM SOITEM
INNER JOIN SO
ON SO.ID=SOITEM.SOID
group by  SO.ID, SOITEM.SOID, SO.CustomerID
ORDER BY SO.ID
```